# Unable to call default Alloy libraries in Ti.Unit Framework

Tags: unit-testing, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

We are planning to use Ti.Unit framework for Unit testing. We use moment alloy library in our project. Default alloy library, not added as file in our project. Issue is, we are unable to call moment or any other default alloy libraries in Ti.Unit test. It is not recognizing alloy default libraries. Any way we can call this library.
var moment = require(/alloy/moment) . How to write in Ti.Unit test?

Comment: Do you have an example unit test we could see?

Comment: Do you have a more elaborated example? I don't understand your setup completely. But your problem might be solved if you add an additional file to the _/helpers_ folder, as seen in _https://github.com/aca-mobile/ti-unit/blob/develop/helpers/underscore-jasmine.js_